# How to sign urls for longer than a week using aws-sdk for Ruby?

Tags: aws-sdk, pre-signed-url

I've been using [marcel/s3](https://github.com/marcel/aws-s3) until we recently had to upgrade to [aws-sdk](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby) (version 2).

One change that we noticed was that we now can't sign URLs with expirations longer than a week, as we get an exception: `ArgumentError: expires_in value of #{X} exceeds one-week maximum`.

I tried overriding the [ONE_WEEK constant](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/blob/master/aws-sdk-core/lib/aws-sdk-core/s3/presigner.rb#L66), which let me create the signed URL. The thing is that now curl the obtained URL I get `400` response including `X-Amz-Expires must be less than a week (in seconds); that is, the given X-Amz-Expires must be less than 604800 seconds`.

How can I sign an URL for longer than a week using `aws-sdk v2` (as I could with `marcel/s3`)? Is switching to `aws-sdk v1` an alternative to achieve this?

The difference I've noted between the URLs generated by each lib:

- `marcel-s3`: uses `AWSAccessKeyId`, `Expires` and `Signature` as query parameters.
- `aws-sdk v2`: uses `X-Amz-Algorithm`, `X-Amz-Credential`, `X-Amz-Date`, `X-Amz-Expires`, `X-Amz-SignedHeaders` and `X-Amz-Signature` as query parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Using v1 of aws-sdk (along with v2 for the other stuff) worked for me. Sample code:

```
def url s3_key, public_path=false
  s3 = AWS::S3.new # aws-sdk v1 s3 client
  v1_obj = s3.buckets[BUCKET_NAME].objects[s3_key]
  if public_path
    v1_obj.public_url.to_s
  else
    v1_obj.url_for(:read, expires: (2.weeks.since - Time.now).to_i).to_s
end
```